# Emacs docview: saving/jumping to locations with

Tags: emacs, elisp, docview

When using doc-view in Emacs, I'd like to jump to different locations (e.g., move to the bibliography of a paper and back to where I was). I've tried using C-u C-SPC and registers to jump to different locations, but it doesn't work when I'm in doc-view mode. So, do you know if there is any way I could save (and jump to) different locations while in the doc-view mode?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't? What is C-SPC bound to, then? Is it something important? Otherwise you can just add a mode-specific hook and steal the keybinding back.

Comment: C-SPC is bound to cua-set-mark when I'm in doc-view-mode. I've also tried to open a pdf file without using my init file but I had the same problem (i.e., it doesn't jump to back to the place where I set mark). Does that only happen with me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal marks don't work, indeed, and registers won't work either, sadly.  But bookmarks will work (e.g. `C-x r m` and `C-x r b`).  I'd welcome patches that try to make registers use the same infrastructure as bookmarks so that they also work under doc-view-mode and friends.